# Mongoose: Operation `schema.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a REST API made with Node.js and I use Mongoose to connect with MongoDB. Whenever I try to interact with the DB using Mongoose, I get the timeout error.

I have made sure that the DB is running and accepts connections from my IP. Using the same connection method in other projects works for some reason.

I am using mobile hotspot connection. Could that be an issue?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const userRoutes = require('../Backend/routes/userRoutes')
const taskRoutes = require('../Backend/routes/taskRoutes')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


require('dotenv').config()
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());



app.use(userRoutes)
app.use(taskRoutes)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000 , () => {
    console.log("API is now running.")
});
```

userRoutes.js

```
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/users/currentUser', userController.getCurrentUserData)

router.get('/users/:userId', userController.getUserData)

router.post('/register', userController.register);

router.post('/login', userController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

Method in userController that causes the error (the error is caused by no matter which method I call out)

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {

    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send("Missing one or all required request body fields: username, password");
    }

    let existingUser;

    try {
        existingUser = await userSchema.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    } catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).send("Internal server error."); //Error comes from here
    }

    if (!existingUser) {
        return res.status(404).send('User not found');
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, existingUser.password);
    if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
        return res.status(401).send('Invalid credentials');
    }

    let token;
    try {
        token = jwt.sign(
            { userId: existingUser._id, username: existingUser.username, tasks: existingUser.tasks},
            process.env.SECRET,
            { expiresIn: "1h" }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send("Couldn't create JWT.")
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ token: token });
}
```

User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    },
    tasks:{
        type:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
    }
})

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION="mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
SECRET='test'
```

Comment: `mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION).then(() => console.log('connected').catch(console.error)` you should handle this promise

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Returns 'connected'

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix this? I'm getting the same error without doing anything from today

Comment: @iuliu.net Hey, I added the mongoose connecting part to a different file and required that file in my server.js. I have no idea what caused it, in other projects it works just fine connecting to mongoose in server.js